# Async Push data to Array in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm calling mongoose query inside of another mongoose query. When I push results to a array, When ever I check it at last it is empty. After seacrching a lot, Found that issue is this executes asynchronously. But can't find how to fix the issue. My code is as follows.

```
    Bus.find().exec(function(err,buses) {

        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        if (buses[0] != null){
            const cords = [];
            buses.forEach( function (bus) {
                // console.log(bus);
                    Position.findOne({"busId": bus.busId},{}, {sort : {'time' : -1}}, function (err, position) {
                        cords.push(position);
                        console.log(cords);
                        // console.log(position);
                    });
                    console.log(cords);
                },
                function (err) {
                    if (err){
                        console.log(err,"Errrrrrrrrrrrrr");
                    }
                });
            console.log(cords);
            res.json({cords: cords});
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,  there are a number of problems with your code, but chief among them is the fact that you cannot save or act upon values you receive inside a callback to anything outside of that callback. Your example has (rewritten  for clarity):

```
var result = []
arry.forEach(function(opt) {
  async.call(args, function(err,value) {
    result.push(value)
  })
})
// result is empty here!
```

Which cannot work as you expect because you can not know when the inner callbacks complete.

By definition, callbacks are triggered *some time in the future*, and since you cannot know when, *you must do all computation using the result passed to a callback* **in the callback itself!**

Doing otherwise will give you inconsistent results.

#### UPDATED - Re comment

(Note: *hastily typed on iPad during train ride, will fix later if needed.*)

The best way would be to use Promises to aggregate the results. Here's a naive example:

```
/* 
 * given a value and an optional array (accum),
 * pass the value to the async func and add its result to accum
 * if accum is not an array, make it one
 * return accum
 */

var do_something = (value, accum) => {
  // on first pass, accum will be undefined, so make it an array
  accum = Array.isArray(accum) ? accum : []
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    async_func(value, (err, res) => {
      if(err) {
        reject(err)
      }
      accum.append(res)
      resolve(accum)
    })
  })
}   

/* 
 * for each member of input array, apply do_something
 * then operate on accumulated result.
 */

Promise.map(input, do_something)
  .then(results => {
    // results will contain the accumulated results from all
    // the mapped operations
  })
  .catch(err => {
    throw err
  })
```

#### UPDATED - per comment

Using callbacks only, you can achieve the same result using:

```
const inputs = [...] // array of inputs to pass to async function

const expected_num_of_results = inputs.length

let results = []

const onComplete = (results) => {
  // do something with completed results here
  console.log(`results: ${results}`);
}

const onResult = (err, res) => { // callback to async_func
  if(err) {
    throw new Error(`on iteration ${results.length+1}: ${err}`)
  }

  results.push(res) // save result to accumulator

  if( results.length >= expected_num_of_results) { // are we done?
    onComplete(results) // process results
  }
}

// example async func - REPLACE with actual async function
const async_func = (val,cb) => {
  // call callback with no error and supplied value multiplied by 2
  cb(null,val*2)
}

// wrapper that takes one value 
// and calls async_func with it and predefined callback
const do_async = (value) => { 
  async_func(value, onResult)
}

// process inputs
inputs.forEach(do_async)
```

So with:

```
const inputs = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

will print:

```
results: 2,4,6,8,10
```

Comment: Can you give me a example of how to do that thing with callbacks! If could that will be a great help!